# Cannot Unit Test Using Fongo fails in 4.1.4 - worked in 3.1.4

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

https://github.com/sanjuthomas/spring-data-mongodb

I have try several examples such as the one above to understand how to unit test mongo applications using fongo.  All the examples examples worked - including the one above but when I upgrade the pom to the latest releases supported in spring boot all the examples fail.  It seems the application context is no longer getting loaded for the test.  Is this unit test functionality broken or do I need to change the code?

Below is the code that fails and used to work in Spring 3 - now the rule fails stating that a mongo instance does not exist in the context:

```
package com.ourownjava.spring.data.mongo.repository;

import static com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.mongodb.MongoDbRule.MongoDbRuleBuilder.newMongoDbRule;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.foursquare.fongo.Fongo;
import com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.annotation.ShouldMatchDataSet;
import com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.annotation.UsingDataSet;
import com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.mongodb.MongoDbRule;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.ourownjava.spring.data.mongo.model.Trade;

/**
 * Spring Data MongoDB Repository Unit testcase.
 * 
 * @author ourownjava.com
 *
 */

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TestTradeRepository {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Rule
    public MongoDbRule mongoDbRule = newMongoDbRule().defaultSpringMongoDb(
            "trade-db");

    @Autowired
    private TradeRepository tradeRepository;


    @Test
    @ShouldMatchDataSet(location = "/testData/trade-t1.json")
    public void shouldSaveTrade(){
        tradeRepository.save(createTrade());
    }

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet(locations = {"/testData/trade-t1.json"})
    public void shouldFindByTraderId(){
        final List<Trade> trades = tradeRepository.findByTraderId("papjac");
        assertNotNull(trades);
        assertTrue(trades.size() > 0);
        assertEquals("papjac", trades.get(0).getTraderId());
    }

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet(locations = {"/testData/trade-t1.json"})
    public void shouldFindByExchangeCode(){
        final List<Trade> trades = tradeRepository.findByExchangeCode("NYSE");
        assertNotNull(trades);
        assertTrue(trades.size() > 0);
        assertEquals("NYSE", trades.get(0).getExchangeCode());
    }


    private Trade createTrade(){
        final Trade trade = new Trade();
        trade.setId("t1");
        trade.setTraderId("papjac");
        trade.setExchangeCode("NYSE");
        trade.setValue(90.3);
        return trade;
    }



    @Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { TradeRepository.class })
    static class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected String getDatabaseName() {
            return "trade-db";
        }

        @Override
        public Mongo mongo() {
            return new Fongo("trade-test").getMongo();
        }

        @Override
        protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
            return "com.ourownjava.spring.data.mongo";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Annotation @Bean for mongo()

```
@Bean 
@Override
public Mongo mongo() {
            return new Fongo("trade-test").getMongo();
}
```